# How can I write JUnit tests for the clipboard in Java?

Tags: java, process, junit, clipboard

My problem with JUnit tests for the clipboard is that Java hold a copy of the clipboard data. That the behavior of the clipboard is completely different if you copy data in the same Java VM or if you copy data in an external process to the system clipboard.

Are there any trick to clear the local copy of the clipboard data? This should work platform independent.

The only idea that I have is to start a second Java process that copy data to the clipboard. But this has a very bad performance if every test start a second JVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you feel the need to test the clipboard?

A better approach would be to test your `Transferable` and assume that the clipboard works as advertised (or it would have been fixed).

Comment: @Horcrux7 - IKVM is a VM written in .Net, correct? If that's the case, then I would expect that any tests are written in C# or some other .Net language, and would have access to the .Net clipboard interfaces. So I'd think that you'd start the VM, execute whatever Java code updates the clipboard, then reset the clipboard via .Net code.